# MY scrapy webscraper is returning only the last quotes

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, data-mining

I wrote this scrapy web scraper to scrape ALL the quotes on the first 10 pages on [this website](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes), after running the code, I discovered that only the last quotes of some of these pages are returned to me.
I need suggestions on how I can make the scrapy spider return all the quotes on all the pages. Here is my code

```
import scrapy
from google_quotes.items import GoogleQuotesItem

start_urls=['https://www.goodreads.com/quotes']
for number in range(1,11):
    page_append='?page={}'.format(str(number))
    start_urls.append('https://www.goodreads.com/quotes{}'.format(page_append))

class quotes(scrapy.Spider):
    name='goodreads_quotes'
    def start_requests(self):
        urls=start_urls
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url,callback=self.parse)
        
    def parse(self,response):
        g_quotes=GoogleQuotesItem()
        quotes=response.css('div .quoteText::text').extract()
        for quote in quotes:
            if len(quote)>10:
                g_quotes['quote']=quote
        return g_quotes
```

The spider moves through all the pages just as I want, but it only returns the last quotes.

Comment: maybe you need to `yield` instead of return?

Comment: I have tried that, but I am still getting the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @flaxon mentioned you need to yield the result. You also need to mind the indentation.

You are also checking if the `quote` variable (which is a string, not a list) is longer than 10, not sure why.

```
def parse(self,response):
    g_quotes = GoogleQuotesItem()
    quotes = response.css('div .quoteText::text').extract()
    for quote in quotes:
        g_quotes['quote'] = quote
        yield g_quotes # Notice the indentation
```

Try this and let me know.

Comment: Damm, the problem was with my indentation. it works fine now. Thanks.